# Run tasks at specific times(millisecond)

Tags: c#, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, multitasking

I need to run multiple tasks or threads at specific times (milliseconds).
I want to send data from the program to my server at defined times.
I use Rest Sharp to send data. I want to send data to the server at times like, for example: 5:46:50.100 millisecond, 5:46:50.150, 5:46:50.200 to 30 times (with a difference of 50 milliseconds ).
I use the following code to do this, but the "Send" function does not execute on time.
Of course, considering the ping delay, this time is added to the ping delay rate, which is true at other times.
Also, I do not want the thread or other tasks to wait for the previous tasks to be executed and to be executed exactly at the specified time, for example, a thread or task that runs at 5:46:50.200 does not wait for the thread or task to run at the time 5:46:50.100

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;
private void SetUpTimer(TimeSpan alertTime)
{
    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime - current.TimeOfDay;
    if (timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        return;
    }
    this.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
    {
        this.Send();
    }, null, timeToGo, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}

private void Send()
{
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), "", "");
    }));
    /*IList<string> startTime = new List<string>();
    startTime.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
    var client = new RestClient("mysite.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("/api", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);

    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv: 79.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 79.0";
    
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;
    /*Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), content, "");
    }));*/
    /*IList<string> contentList = new List<string>();
    contentList.Add(response.Content);
    IList<string> endTime = new List<string>();
    endTime.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
    for (int i = 0; i < startTime.Count; i++)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", startTime.ElementAt(i), contentList.ElementAt(i), endTime.ElementAt(i));
        }));
    }*/

}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int mili = Convert.ToInt32(txtMili.Text);
    int dist = Convert.ToInt32(txtDistance.Text);
    int sec = Convert.ToInt32(txtSec.Text);
    for (int i=0; i < Convert.ToInt32(txtCount.Text); i++)
    {
        SetUpTimer(new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text), sec, mili));
        //mili = (mili + dist < 1000) ? mili + dist : (mili + dist) - 1000;
        mili = mili + dist;
        if (mili > 1000)
        {
            mili = mili - 1000;
            sec = sec + 1;
        }
        
    }
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

But the result that is obtained after executing the code is as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNr4C.png)

Comment: You are getting `DateTime.Now` for the grid **after** you have made the web request. Of course that time is not gonna match the start time of the timer call.

Comment: Why do you need to send so many requests so quickly? And why are you bothered about exact milliseconds? What is the purpose of all this? It seems like a strange task

Comment: @Xerillio It does not matter then. These times are not accurate in Fidler software either

Comment: As ADyson asks, why is this important? Obtaining millisecond precision with something as unpredictable as web requests is gonna be practically impossible.

Comment: @ADyson I want to send data to my server at specific times. Where is this strange?

Comment: @Xerillio I just want one or more tasks or threads to be executed in the allotted time (milliseconds). Please note this

Comment: @Xerillio I have seen a program that sends http requests at specified times (milliseconds). It's not hard work I did not work with c# programming. I am a php programmer!

Comment: Because you're being pedantically specific, like 100 milliseconds specific, and incredibly frequent as well. The only use case I can think of for sending requests at that frequency to a web service is some sort of DDOS attack. As for being worried about exact milliseconds, as xerillo says that's very difficult to achieve repeatedly, there are too many factors outside your control

Answer (score 2):

A list of issues you're gonna have hard time fixing (and this is far from a complete list):

- For each web request there's some setup before the request actually "leaves" the client.
- You only have a certain amount of resources (CPU, I/O) that limits how much you can do at the same time if each request takes longer to complete than the amount of time between each request. This is true both on the client and server side.
- The network you're on may be slow, temporarily down or other things in the network stack are delaying the request. Again both on the server and client side.
- Maybe most importantly: the clock on your client and server are never guaranteed to be perfectly synchronized by default - especially not down to milliseconds. So even if it took you less than 1 millisecond to send the request from client to server, they are both gonna have a different timestamp. As @chux mentions, there are protocols like [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) that can help minimize the difference but this requires some additional setup.

So, unless you can find a way to magically avoid all of these issues (many of which you have no control over), what you are trying to do is pretty much impossible.

---

**Update for debugging your code:**

Please try to use the following as your `Send` function:

```
private void Send()
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    var client = new RestClient("mysite.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("/api", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);

    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv: 79.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 79.0";
    
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var requestEndTime = DateTime.Now;
    var content = response.Content;
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // This lambda function "() => {...}" is called asynchronously, which
        // means that calling "DateTime.Now" in here will give you a wrong
        // timestamp, so you need to save those timestamps earlier like this

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
            "",
            startTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"),
            content,
            requestEndTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
    }));
}
```

Please run your code with the above function and update your question to show the latest results. Do you still see incorrect starting timestamps?

Comment: "clock on your client and server are never guaranteed to be perfectly synchronized - especially not down to milliseconds" --> Note that [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) can achieve "clock accuracy in the sub-microsecond range" and [IEEE 1588-2019](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/1588-2019.html) suggests "Sub-nanosecond time transfer accuracy can be achieved in a properly designed network."  The quality of implementation does matter though.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good point. I've added it to the answer for reference.

Comment: @Xerillio I want to create multiple threads or tasks to be executed at specified times. I do not care about server and client time! I just want the threads or tasks to be executed on time For example, thread 1 should be executed at 16:00:00.100, thread 2 at 16:00:00.200, etc. Is this method optimal? Do you have a more efficient method?

Comment: Please give less negative points. Let us ask questions too! It is not important for me to send a request! Which you explain about server time. Server or network time does not matter when the thread start at the time specified in the client!

Comment: @av2020 you should answer my previous question first before I can help: what are the timestamps of your application right now? You need to measure this in the beginning of the `Send` method. But it's still not clear why you want this either. If you don't care about the timestamp on the server, then why do you care at all?

Comment: @Xerillio I use client timestamp! I do not care about server timestamp!! In Client, I want thread 1 to start at 16:00:00.100 and execute the Send method! This thread may last until 16:00:00.300, it does not matter to me. I want the Send method to run again at 16:00:00.200 and not wait for a response from thread 1

Comment: @av2020 look at my very first comment to your question. You have not yet shown to us that your current implementation is wrong. **Please** add `DateTime.Now` to the beginning of `Send()` and show us which timestamps you get.

Comment: @Xerillio I did this and you can see the result in this photo. The interval between each run is 50 milliseconds, but in rows 15 and 16 it shows the same timestamp.
https://pasteboard.co/JtkPpMp.png

Comment: @av2020 if you update your question with this info as well as the code you used to make these results, then it's easier to figure out why you get these numbers

Comment: I updated the question and put the code in it @Xerillio

Comment: @av2020 sorry for the delay. I've updated my answer with some code for you to test. Please let me know which results you get with my example.